# How to prevent ads from accessing and changing data on my own website

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy, websecurity

Suppose the Javascript on my site has data in the `localStorage` like this:

```
<script>
    localStorage['my_website'] = "https://my_website.com";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bad_website.com/bad.js"></script>
```

The `bad.js` from another site can read and write the `localStorage['my_website']`. That is quite surprising to me because I thought the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is enforced by every browser automatically. Am I missing something totally?

If the `bad.js` can change the business logic of your Javascript, does that mean the ads run by your website can change many parts of your website?

Anyway, could you please comment on the issue? Do I have to do something to prevent cross domain access?

Thanks.

Comment: Read up on server side Content Security Policy headers. [Good start on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Comment: You put your evil code in an iframe which will prevent the evil js in another domain accessing your DOM. I have seen many ads using this approach. Also i remember seeing iframes when i added the facebook "like button" and amazons' affiliate link in my website.

Comment: DOM is not my primary concern now. It is totally shocking to me that your JavaScript variables can be accessed by somebody else! Developers use a lot of JavaScript libraries, which cannot be scanned for threats. Imagine those libraries can read information stored in your variables and send it back to their websites without your permission!

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. That helps. I don't know why the same-origin policy concept still hangs around uselessly while the Content Security Policy is doing the job. I hope the same-origin policy won't mislead people anymore after they read your advice.

Comment: same origin policy doesn't apply to remote script src. Think of all the remote CDN scripts that would break for example.